# Perl Protein Seq. ID and SQ and "//"

Tags: perl

So the new Mission is to Download the File from the Website (http://ceres.primus-fatum.de/~fate/scriptsprachen/uniprotDB_part.txt) and then i must to du an subroutine to save line by line and then search for ID and Sq .. and All of that should saved in new Txt file : 1. Id Line should be at first , 2. SQ at last 3. Everything else should come between ID and SQ and at the End should come Salsh .... here is an Example.. but the File have 1000 Example

Example of the output expected:

```
ID   001R_FRG3G              Reviewed;         256 AA.   -> ID First place *****

AC   Q6GZX4;

DT   28-JUN-2011, integrated into UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot.

DT   19-JUL-2004, sequence version 1.

DT   18-APR-2012, entry version 24.

DE   RecName: Full=Putative transcription factor 001R;

GN   ORFNames=FV3-001R;

OS   Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3).

OC   Viruses; dsDNA viruses, no RNA stage; Iridoviridae; Ranavirus.

OX   NCBI_TaxID=654924;

OH   NCBI_TaxID=8295; Ambystoma (mole salamanders).

OH   NCBI_TaxID=30343; Hyla versicolor (chameleon treefrog).

OH   NCBI_TaxID=8316; Notophthalmus viridescens (Eastern newt) (Triturus viridescens).

OH   NCBI_TaxID=8404; Rana pipiens (Northern leopard frog).

OH   NCBI_TaxID=45438; Rana sylvatica (Wood frog).

RN   [1]

RP   NUCLEOTIDE SEQUENCE [LARGE SCALE GENOMIC DNA].

RX   PubMed=15165820; DOI=10.1016/j.virol.2004.02.019;

RA   Tan W.G., Barkman T.J., Gregory Chinchar V., Essani K.;

RT   "Comparative genomic analyses of frog virus 3, type species of the

RT   genus Ranavirus (family Iridoviridae).";

RL   Virology 323:70-84(2004).

CC   -!- FUNCTION: Transcription activation (Potential).

CC   -----------------------------------------------------------------------

CC   Copyrighted by the UniProt Consortium, see http://www.uniprot.org/terms

CC   Distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivs License

CC   -----------------------------------------------------------------------

DR   EMBL; AY548484; AAT09660.1; -; Genomic_DNA.

DR   RefSeq; YP_031579.1; NC_005946.1.

DR   ProteinModelPortal; Q6GZX4; -.

DR   GeneID; 2947773; -.

DR   ProtClustDB; CLSP2511514; -.

DR   GO; GO:0006355; P:regulation of transcription, DNA-dependent; IEA:UniProtKB-KW.

DR   GO; GO:0046782; P:regulation of viral transcription; IEA:InterPro.

DR   GO; GO:0006351; P:transcription, DNA-dependent; IEA:UniProtKB-KW.

DR   InterPro; IPR007031; Poxvirus_VLTF3.

DR   Pfam; PF04947; Pox_VLTF3; 1.

PE   4: Predicted;

KW   Activator; Complete proteome; Reference proteome; Transcription;

KW   Transcription regulation.

FT   CHAIN         1    256       Putative transcription factor 001R.

FT                                /FTId=PRO_0000410512.

FT   COMPBIAS     14     17       Poly-Arg.

SQ   SEQUENCE   256 AA;  29735 MW;  B4840739BF7D4121 CRC64;    -> SQ at LAST and then "//"
     MAFSAEDVLK EYDRRRRMEA LLLSLYYPND RKLLDYKEWS PPRVQVECPK APVEWNNPPS
     EKGLIVGHFS GIKYKGEKAQ ASEVDVNKMC CWVSKFKDAM RRYQGIQTCK IPGKVLSDLD
     AKIKAYNLTV EGVEGFVRYS RVTKQHVAAF LKELRHSKQY ENVNLIHYIL TDKRVDIQHL
     EKDLVKDFKA LVESAHRMRQ GHMINVKYIL YQLLKKHGHG PDGPDILTVK TGSKGVLYDD
     SFRKIYTDLG WKFTPL

//
```

I have tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {
   my @file_data=();
   my $motif ='';
   my $protein_seq='';
   my $h= '[VLIM]';   
   my $s= '[AG]';
   my $x= '[ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV]';
   my $regexp = "($I){1}D"; ->motif to be searched is  ID
   my $regexp = "($S){1}Q"; ->motif to be searched is  SQ

   my @locations=();

   @file_data= get_file_data("seq.txt");
   $protein_seq= extract_sequence(@file_data); 

    foreach my $line(@file_data){
      if ($motif=~ /$regexp/){
      print "found motif \n\n";
    } else {
      print "not found \n\n";
    }
}
```

Recording the location/position of motif to be outputed..

```
    @locations= match_position($regexp,$seq);
    if (@locations){ 
    print "Searching for motifs $regexp \n";
    print "Catalytic site is at location:\n";
    }
    else{
    print "motif not found \n\n";
    }
    exit;

    sub get_file_data{
        #body...

    my ($filename)=@_;
    my $sequence='';

    foreach my $line(@file_data){

    if ($line=~ /^\s*$/){
    next;
            }
    elsif ($line=~ /^\s*#/){
    next;
    }
    elsif ($line=~ /^>/){
    next;
    }
    else {
    $sequence.=$line;
    }
    }
    $sequence=~ s/\s//g;
    return $sequence;
    }

    sub(match_positions) {
    my ($regexp, $sequence)=@_;
    use strict;
    my @position=();
    while ($sequence=~ /$regexp/ig){
    push (@position, $-[0]);
    }
    return @position;
    }

    }

    main();
```

Comment: Iam an Beginner, studying BioInformatics first Sem. and the thing is we cant use LWP so i dont know how to download the content of the Website, anyidea how should i start? and how can i save them after that?

Comment: Why can't you use lwp, its the best way to download files in perl?

Comment: so i ask my assistent and he mean i dont need to do that ... he saied u just have to download the file and then open it and contuniue the work ...

Comment: for bioinformatics type questions, you might also want to check out: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: thx btw its helped me a little bit but i need a code !!

Comment: I'm a little confused by what the output should be exactly. Are you splitting the text file in the link to 1000 text files? And appending "-> ID First place *****" to the first line and "-> SQ at LAST and then "//"" to the last line and keeping everything else the same?

Comment: What do you want achieve? What output you need? Nobody understand what you want do with the big textfile. We don't really need know than youre an young girl & student, but NEED to know what output you want :) :)

Comment: i just want 2 dimensonal array that the file that u download should look the same as the example ....
Id first then everything else and then Sq and then //, i think its something like spliting not sure.. thats all .. thx btw.

Comment: Nora can you edit your question and add some example output? Like what do you want the array to look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try

make a workspace

```
mkdir protein
cd protein
```

download

```
curl http://ceres.primus-fatum.de/~fate/scriptsprachen/uniprotDB_part.txt > uniprotDB_part.txt
```

or

```
wget http://ceres.primus-fatum.de/~fate/scriptsprachen/uniprotDB_part.txt
```

split

```
csplit -n 6 -k uniprotDB_part.txt '/^ID /' '{100000}'
```

you will get zilion file `xx000000` to `xx00nnnnn` and each will contain one part.

All with simple unix tools. If you don't know anything from `perl` - it is pointless to ask.

Comment: Some help guys iam Stuck, its not that i dont know anything about perl but iam an beginner and idont know how to finish this job.. so somehelp !! iam trying since moprnings and i cant solve it!!. thx anyway